# split string with space in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, split, mysql-workbench

i have data like

```
Name
-----------------
Ram Mohan
Ram Lal Mohan
Ram K Lal Mohan
...
```

I am using:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,' ',1) from contact
```

to get first name

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,' ',-1) from contact
```

to get last name

am getting data like

```
first name     last name
------------------------
Ram              Mohan
Ram              Mohan
Ram              Mohan
```

but data i should get be like

```
    first name     last name
------------------------
Ram              Mohan
Ram Lal          Mohan
Ram K Lal        Mohan
```

only last word after space should come in last name
rest should come in first name

can some one help me in finding a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex replacement here, assuming you are on MySQL 8+:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(Name, '\\s+\\S+$', '') AS first,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,' ', -1) AS last
FROM contact;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

For earlier versions of MySQL, and assuming that the last name would never appear anywhere else in the name, you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` along with `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT
    REPLACE(Name, CONCAT(' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,' ', -1)), '') AS first,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,' ', -1) AS last
FROM contact;
```

### Demo

This second approach basically justs deletes off the last name (plus leading space) which you were already correctly finding using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.  What is left behind should be the first, middle, etc., components you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get the last name, you can remove that number of characters to get the first name.

```
select
    trim(left(Name,char_length(Name)-char_length(substring_index(Name,' ',-1)))) first_name,
    substring_index(Name,' ',-1) last_name
from contact
```

Do note that last names can have spaces in them (e.g. "Walter de la Mare").

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9c2cb90c670fc46a97570e747cca53e4)